# How to prevent a postback call in a lightbox/modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a lightbox/modal that displays a form, but in select tag has a postback call, which keeps closes my lightbox. Is there a way to prevent the postback call using javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                var display = $('.lightbox-overlay').css('display');
                $('.lightbox').click(function (e) {
                    if ($('.lightbox-overlay').length != 0) {
                        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
                    }
                    $('.lightbox-overlay').animate({ 'opacity': '.9' }, 300, 'linear');
                    $('.dialog-ui').animate({ 'opacity': '1.00' }, 300, 'linear');
                    $('.lightbox-overlay, .dialog-ui').css('display', 'block');
                    e.preventDefault();
                });

                $('.close-btn').click(function () {
                    closeBox();
                });

                $('.lightbox-overlay').click(function () {
                    closeBox();
                });
            });

            function closeBox() {
                $('.lightbox-overlay, .dialog-ui').css('display', 'none');
                $("body").css("overflow", "visible");
            }
```

HTML

```
    <a class="lightbox click-here-link" href="#">click here</a>
    <div class="dialog-ui">
    <div class="inner">
        <a class="close-btn" href="#">close</a>
        <h3>Build your product</h3>

        <div class="data-row clearfix">     <span class="product-build-steps">1</span><span id="ctl21_pb_LBL_og1150"><label>Select Hand</label></span> <select id="ctl21_pb_DDL_og1150" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl21$pb_DDL_og1150\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl21$pb_DDL_og1150">   <option value="HRH" selected="selected">Right Hand</option>     <option value="LRH">Left Hand (+£1.99)</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#selectTag').change(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

this way, the select stops doing what it should do

try this:

```
var container = //dom selector for the div or whatever that has all the selects
$(container).find('select').each(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr('onchange');
});
```

If this is ASP.NET, the __doPostBack() function is declared on the onclick attribute so, this way, you will be able to avoid the postback.

Comment: that didn't work, a slight delay but still closes the lightbox. I don't have any control on adding a id's to elements. Forgot to say there is more than one select element on the page and they all have _postbacks

Comment: Yes it is written in ASP.NET will try you suggestion

Comment: Thanks that worked :) $('.dialog-ui').find('select').each(function () {$(this).removeAttr('onchange');});

Answer (score 0):

You can just return false from `form` submit handler to prevent the form to get posted. Try this.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
     //You might have to add some condition here before returning false
     return false;
});
```